# Cycle of multiple iterables?

Tags: python

Given:

```
x = ['a','b','c','d','e']
y = ['1','2','3']
```

I'd like iterate resulting in:

```
a, 1
b, 2
c, 3
d, 1
e, 2
a, 3
b, 1
```

... where the two iterables cycle independently until a given count.

Python's cycle(iterable) can do this w/ 1 iterable.  Functions such as map and itertools.izip_longest can take a function to handle None, but do not provide the built-in auto-repeat.

A not-so-crafty idea is to just concatenate each list to a certain size from which I can iterate evenly.  (Boooo!)

Suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import itertools
x = ['a','b','c','d','e']
y = ['1','2','3']
for a, b in itertools.izip(itertools.cycle(x), itertools.cycle(y)):
    print a, b
```

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way to do this is in `cyclezip1` below. It is fast enough for most purposes.

```
import itertools

def cyclezip1(it1, it2, count):
    pairs = itertools.izip(itertools.cycle(iter1),
                           itertools.cycle(iter2))
    return itertools.islice(pairs, 0, count)
```

Here is another implementation of it that is about twice as fast when `count` is significantly larger than the least common multiple of `it1` and `it2`.

```
import fractions

def cyclezip2(co1, co2, count):
    l1 = len(co1)
    l2 = len(co2)
    lcm = l1 * l2 / float(fractions.gcd(l1, l2))
    pairs = itertools.izip(itertools.cycle(co1),
                           itertools.cycle(co2))
    pairs = itertools.islice(pairs, 0, lcm)
    pairs = itertools.cycle(pairs)
    return itertools.islice(pairs, 0, count)
```

here we take advantage of the fact that pairs will cycle after the first `n` of them where `n`  is the least common mutliple of  `len(it1)` and  `len(it2)`. This of course assumes that the iterables are collections so that asking for the length of them makes any sense. A further optimization that can be made is to 
replace the line

```
pairs = itertools.islice(pairs, 0, lcm)
```

with

```
pairs = list(itertools.islice(pairs, 0, lcm))
```

This is not nearly as dramatic of an improvement (about 2% in my testing) and not nearly as consistent. it also requires more memory. If `it1` and `it2` were known in advance to be small enough so that the additional memory was negligible, then you could squeeze that extra performance out of it.

It's interesting to note that the obvious thing to do in the case of a collection is about four times slower than the first option presented.

```
def cyclezip3(co1, co2, count):
    l1 = len(co1)
    l2 = len(co2)
    return ((co1[i%l1], co2[i%l2]) for i in xrange(count))
```